# Subprocess.Popen() hanging even with shell=False and p.communicate()

Tags: python, subprocess

I am desperate as I am battling since weeks now with subprocess.Popen() hanging. I read a lot of forums with sometime contradictory information and tried as many of them but still without any mean to resolve the issue.

Basically what I simply need is to execute X subprocesses that will run a command and I even do not need their stdout or stderr. They are all writing to sub xml files dedicate to each one of them and I collect them all once they have all finished. The command to be executed is running a python script where I can see it is arriving at the end line in the script logs. I even added a sys.exit() at the end of the called script to make sure it exists properly.

Simplified code looks like:

```
for cmd in commands:
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd[0], shell=False)
    processes.append(p)

# We now pause execution on the main process by 'joining' all of our started sub processes.
# This ensures that each has finished processing their own batch.
for index, process in enumerate(processes):
    logging.info(f"Waiting for process #{index}")
    try:
        (out, err) = process.communicate(timeout=3600)
        outputs.append(out) # not even required
        errors.append(err) # not even required
        process.wait()
        logging.info(f"Process #{index} finished")
    except TimeoutExpired as timeout_err:
        logging.exception(f"Timeout Exception from process #{index}", timeout_err)
        process.kill()
        (out, err) = process.communicate()
    # Reading sub xml
    # reading generated xml for the sub process here
```

Not sure what can be deadlocking here ! even the timeout scenario is not raising properly. And it is unpredictable when it is going to actually hang ...

Any help or support is much appreciated.

Thanks.

**EDIT**
As pointed ou from @MauriceMeyer, the current given timeout is happening sequentially but  I have no means to make it start at the time I call subprocess.Popen(). Also this is a very painful workaround as I can't predict exactly the timeout value and it is killing performance while the whole subprocess story was aimed for having better execution performance.

Comment: `(out, err) = process.communicate(timeout=3600)` is going to wait for each process to finish or kill it after one hour, **sequentially**.

Comment: thanks you for your input - indeed good catch as it starts the timer only at that line - thought it would count it from when the subprocess was executed. I have no means to give timeout value to subprocess.Popen().
I really need to know why it hangs in the first place knowing that the executed command exits properly (it is a python script)

Answer (score 1):

You could manually check if a process needs to get killed:

```
import time
import subprocess

TIMEOUT = 5

processes = []
for x in range(1, 10):
    cmd = [f'sleep {x}']
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True) # shell=True for simplicity!

    # add start time, so we can manually kill the process
    processes.append({'handle': p, 'start': time.time(), 'returncode': None})

_allFinished = False
while not all([p['returncode'] is not None for p in processes]):
    for i, process in enumerate(processes):
        # poll() checks if child process has terminated, returns None if it is running
        rtc = process["handle"].poll()

        if rtc is None:
            # Process is still running, check if it needs to get killed
            if time.time() - process['start'] > TIMEOUT:
                # kills the process!
                process["handle"].terminate()
                process["handle"].wait()
                processes[i]['returncode'] = 'timeout'
        else:
            processes[i]['returncode'] = rtc

    time.sleep(0.1)

for p in processes:
    print(p)
```

Out:

```
{'handle': <subprocess.Popen object at 0x10d4d3040>, 'start': 1644318572.923203, 'returncode': 0}
{'handle': <subprocess.Popen object at 0x10d4ee7c0>, 'start': 1644318572.9256551, 'returncode': 0}
{'handle': <subprocess.Popen object at 0x10d550d30>, 'start': 1644318572.928237, 'returncode': 0}
{'handle': <subprocess.Popen object at 0x10d550d90>, 'start': 1644318572.930966, 'returncode': 0}
{'handle': <subprocess.Popen object at 0x10d50fa60>, 'start': 1644318572.934939, 'returncode': 0}
{'handle': <subprocess.Popen object at 0x10d805250>, 'start': 1644318572.937738, 'returncode': 'timeout'}
{'handle': <subprocess.Popen object at 0x10d82f250>, 'start': 1644318572.940351, 'returncode': 'timeout'}
{'handle': <subprocess.Popen object at 0x10d82f370>, 'start': 1644318572.943875, 'returncode': 'timeout'}
{'handle': <subprocess.Popen object at 0x10d82f490>, 'start': 1644318572.946584, 'returncode': 'timeout'}
```

Comment: Thanks Maurice this is very helpful to correct my timeout issue when process is not terminating as expected. I still need to find why this is happening in the first place.